# error C2220: warning treated as error-no 'object' file generated in driver development

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am Trying to develop a sample driver with the code:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include<wdm.h>
DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(__inout PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject,__in PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    DbgPrint("Driver has been loaded");
    return(STATUS_SUCCESS);
}
```

But it is showing me an error of

```
"error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated"
```

please Help Me!!
Thanks

Comment: And which warning was shown before?

Comment: Is your real code surrounded by backtick quotes like that?

Comment: its real code for now I am trying to learn how to develop a driver in windows and starting from this code..

Comment: @DigvijayRathore: So your real code does have backtick characters in it? Get rid of them. And tell us all the warnings and errors, not just the one that says that some other warning caused a problem.

Comment: It is a compiler option, /WX is "treat warnings as errors".  It keeps programmers honest, helping them to avoid ignoring warnings.  Which matters rather a lot when you write a device driver, you want code to be squeaky-clean since small problems cause big hard-to-diagnose crashes.  You might want to consider keeping this project on the shelf for a while and spend time learning the toolset first.

Comment: @HansPassant I already tried That making all level and tried but still not working If I change the /wx to off mode then it start showing an error that "DriverEntry already defined in Driver.obj"

Comment: Don't ignore warnings.  Next thing that goes wrong is that the compiler won't stop anymore and now the linker can produce errors.  You cannot ignore them.  It is a very basic error, you cannot write a driver when you don't know the basics.  Master the basics first.

Comment: I am Not ignoring the warning at all. I am trying to find the solution of that problem. I tried the above thing so that I could be sure about the problem and I am reading the basics carefully as I am getting it in front of me.  if You have any idea about this error then only please comment@HansPassant

Comment: NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
 __inout PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject,
 __in    PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
 ){
 NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
 return status;
}
If I use that code then it starts generating this error as shown above. But when I am using NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
 __inout PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject,
 __in    PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
 ); is build succussfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- remove DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry; Line
- Unreference registerObject using UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER
- register filter using FltRegisterFilter See the definition on msdn
- Use RtlInitUnicodeString
- DbgPrint("Driver Entry !!!!!");

The Process should be followed May be this is giving you error because of UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER has not been used.